# Replacing a String with Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, text

Suppose that I have a text like "Hello @c1, please go here and play with @c12, @c1 goes and plays", I would like to write a pattern to replace all of @c1 with some value but in the same time the regular expression must not change @c12 or @c123 etc.. 
it should replace only the matched string. I have been trying for hours, but failing to produce the right output, so can anyone can help me with what to do regarding it with articles or code samples

I am using .Net Framework for writing the Regular expression

Comment: What about `@c1a`? Must it be changed or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
@c1\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ1fI4/2)**

[image]

The idea is to use a word boundary after your text and that would solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a word boundary `\b` or [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) here.

A word boundary asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

```
String s = "Hello @c1, please go play with @c12 and @c123";
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"@c1\b", "foo");
Console.WriteLine(r); //=> "Hello foo, please go play with @c12 and @c123"
```

Negative Lookahead asserts that at that position in the string, what immediately follows is not a digit.

```
String s = "Hello @c1, please go play with @c12 and @c123";
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"@c1(?!\d)", "foo");
Console.WriteLine(r); //=> "Hello foo, please go play with @c12 and @c123"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@c1(?![a-zA-Z0-9])
```

you can do this using negative lookahead

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookahead and lookbehind,

```
(?<=\W|^)@c1(?=\W|$)
```

Code:

```
string str = "Hello @c1, please go here and play with @c12, @c1 goes and plays";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=\W|^)@c1(?=\W|$)", "foo");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/nvCJTD)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
@c(?=1\D)1
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/M4QFM23FH3)